# javascript - stop refresh if error is returned from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I was wondering whether it would be possible to add something to my javascript which would allow a refresh if the form is submitted fine however will not refresh the page if an error is returned back from PHP.

is this possible? if so could anyone provide me with any guidance that will help me achieve this please. I have manage to get the javascript to refresh when the form is submitted and a message is returned.

this is the js:

```
function addCall() {
  var data = $('#addForm').serialize();
  $.post('../Admin/ManageCourses_AddSubmit.php', data, function(response){

    $("#addForm").html(response);
    //'soft'reload parent page, after a delay to show message
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#addModal').modal('hide')
      location.reload();
    },3500);

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

and the php which processes the form and validates it:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (empty($_POST['course_title'])) {
   $message = " Value is required";
} 

else {

    $course_title           = trim($_POST['course_title']);

    # Validate Course #

    if (!ctype_alpha($course_title)) {

        $message = '<p class="error">Course title should be alpha characters only.</p>';
    }

    elseif (strlen($course_title) < 3 OR strlen($course_title) > 50) {
        $message = '<p class="error">Course title should be within 3-50 characters long.</p>';
    }

    else {

        include "../includes/db_conx.php";

        try
        {
            $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
            $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO `insights`.`course_details` (`course_title`) VALUES (:course_title)");
            $sql->bindParam(':course_title', $course_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sql->execute();

            $message = "<p class='text-success'> Record Successfully Added <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/></p>";
        } 
        catch(Exception $e) {

            if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
            {
                $message = 'Course already exists in database';
            }
            else 
            {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
die($message);
?>
```

It would really useful to the user to be able to make amendments to the form instead of rewriting it all again.

the form:

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Record: </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form id="addForm" class="addForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="control-label" for="forename">Forename:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="forename" name="forename" type="text" placeholder="Enter forename(s)" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required="">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="surname">Surname:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Enter surname" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required="">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Text input-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email" class="form-control" maxlength="255" value="" required="">

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control" value="" maxlength="50" required="">

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" maxlength="40" required="">

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="control-label" for="confirm_password">Confirm Password:</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="retype password" class="form-control" maxlength="40" required="">

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <?php

                                    include "../includes/db_conx.php";

                                    try {

                                        $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

                                        $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                        $stmt2 = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM role_type');
                                        $stmt2->execute();
                                        $roles = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    }

                                    catch(Exception $e)
                                    {
                                        die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="role_type">Select User Type:</label><p></p>
                                        <select name="role">
                                            <option value=''>Select One</option>";
                                            <?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $role['role_type_code'] ?>"><?php echo $role['role_title'] ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <p></p>

                                <?php

                                    include "../includes/db_conx.php";

                                    try {

                                        $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

                                        $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                        $stmt3 = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT * FROM course_details ORDER BY course_title');
                                        $stmt3->execute();
                                        $courses = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    }

                                    catch(Exception $e)
                                    {
                                        die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="course_details">Select Course:</label><p></p>
                                        <select name="course">
                                            <option value=''>Select One</option>";
                                            <?php foreach($courses as $course): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $course['course_code'] ?>"><?php echo $course['course_title'] ?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
                            </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="pull-right" onclick="addUCall();">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hmm.. It's been a long time since the last time I used PHP. However, I think you can return submitted data from PHP and check it in your js callback if it return success or not. Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message variable contain both error and success message. It will reload page every time when it receives response.
Add this after $("#addForm").html(response); -

```
var n = response.search("class=\'text-success\'");
if(n!=-1){
      //reload success
}
else{
     //stay on page, errors
}
```

Comment: this works great however i've just realise the modal the form is displayed on still removes all the form fields when submit is clicked. I have attached the modal form to the original question. do you know how i can put the response into the form instead of it removing the form input please

Comment: write this `$("#addForm").prepend(response);` instead of `$("#addForm").html(response);`

Comment: thank you very much. That works really well except every time i encounter an error message it stays logged at the top in addition to any new ones. Is there a way to overcome this? for example if i don't enter a forename ill get an error message and then later i miss something else the first error message would still be there

Comment: you should also disable submit button after hitting form because you are reloading page after 3.5 seconds and if user hits submit button again in this time then you'll get duplicate entries.
`$(".btn-success").attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: `$(".error").remove();` `$(".text-success").remove();`
add these at the top in the function. This will remove previous messages and prepend new one

Answer (score 1):

As you're returning the error messages in the response, check for the error class and do the reload if necessary.

```
    $.post('../Admin/ManageCourses_AddSubmit.php', data, function(response){

        if(response.contains("text-success")) {
           // put your logic here for success
        } else {
          // logic for errors
        }
   });
```